# I'm looking for a site about logic circuits

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I can't find any site that will answer my question about logic circuits. The question is below, please lead me to the proper site.

> I'm currently studying logic circuits for my exams and came across a question:
>   "7. An electrical circuit is set up with four switches. A lamp will light only if the following happens: 1) Switches A and B are both on. 2) Either Switch C or Switch D is on, but not both. Draw a logic circuit to represent this"
>
> I made a AND gate for A and B, made an XOR gate for C and D but don't know how to close the circuit into one output as I now have two outputs. I hope you guys understand my situation and help with it. Thank you.

If this is the wrong site, please lead me to the correct site, please.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com perhaps?

Comment: With some polish, yeah, and not in the form of "I came across a question" - just talk about your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SamuelLiew notes in the comments, [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) has questions about topic, especially in the [[logic-gates] tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-gates). I've browsed some similar-looking questions and the reception seems to be mixed: [good](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/329935/113522) (though probably skewed by HNQ votes), [decent](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/157516/113522) and [subpar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/159523/113522). You've already included your own attempts to solving the problem which is a good sign.